# Oracle - Can't login with "/ as sysdba", but can with "sys as sysdba"

Tags: oracle, errors, logins, docker, oracle-18c

I've been working on setting up a docker container running Oracle DB XE 18.4.0. I have the container built from [Oracle's dockerfiles](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images) and it is working fine, except that I cannot login using

`connect / as sysdba`

in a sqlplus prompt from inside the container, but

`connect sys as sysdba`

does work. The error message that I receive is

`ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

I checked that my `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$ORACLE_SID` environment variables were set and they look fine. I'm trying to install APEX in this container and the first error that is displayed when running the install script is the failed login error above where the script runs `connect / as sysdba`.

When installing Apex on the local instance of Oracle DB on my development environment, Everything works as expected.

I am working from a Windows 10 (1803) machine which is running docker 18.03.0-ce with a VirtualBox 6.0.2 setup.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying this with not oracle user, or the environment variable `TWO_TASK` is set.

Comment: @BalazsPapp that fixed it! `docker exec -it /bin/bash` connects as root, so switching to the user `oracle` fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @BalazsPapp who pointed this out in the comment to my question.

To use `conn / as sysdba`, I had to be logged in as the user `oracle` instead of root.

Switching to the `oracle` user and attempting to login again solved the problem.